# Single Font for displaying ordinary alphanumeric characters and arrows

Tags: fonts, arrows

Is there a commonly used font which will allow the display of up and down arrows as well as ordinary alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 0):

Web Dingbats I suppose, is this for webdesign or something else? And are you on a Mac or a PC? I found a method to include fonts on the website, so it doesn't depend on default browser, or system fonts. Let me know.

Comment: not for web design. Using delphi and am writing to a box which can only take text of a single font